# setInterval delays not accurate

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm currently creating a countdown using setInterval though at the moment it runs slower than it should. According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval), the delay parameter is in milliseconds however it isn't accurate.

I compared my countdown to the one on my phone and the phone runs nearly 5 times faster.

```
    var count = setInterval( function() {
            if (iMil == 0) {
                if (iS == 0) {
                    if (iMin == 0) {
                        if (iH == 0) {
                            // DONE
                        } else {
                            iH--;
                            iMin = 59;
                            iS = 59;
                            iMil = 999;
                        }
                    } else {
                        iMin--;
                        iS = 59;
                        iMil == 999;
                    }
                } else {
                    iS--;
                    iMil = 999;
                }
            } else {
                iMil--;
            }
            hours.text(iH);
            minutes.text(iMin);
            seconds.text(iS);
            milliseconds.text(iMil);
        }, 1 );
```

This is the main part of my script. The variables `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds` and `milliseconds` are jQuery object elements.

What I'm getting at is, is there a reason that it runs slower than it is supposed too?

Comment: see also [How to create an accurate timer in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29971898/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInterval()` is not guaranteed to run perfectly on time in javascript.  That's partly because JS is single threaded and partly for other reasons.  If you want to display a time with `setInterval()` then get the current time on each timer tick and display that.  The `setInterval()` won't be your timer, but just a recurring screen update mechanism.  Your time display will always be accurate if you do it that way.

In addition, no browser will guarantee a call to your interval at 1ms intervals.  In fact, many browsers will never call `setInterval` more often than every 5ms and some even longer than that.  Plus, if there are any other events happening in the browser with other code responding to those events, the `setInterval()` call might be delayed even longer.  The HTML5 spec proposes 4ms as the shortest interval for `setTimeout()` and 10ms as the shortest interval for `setInterval()`, but allows the implementor to use longer minimum times if desired.

In fact, if you look at [this draft spec for timers](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html), step 5 of the algorithm says:

> If timeout is less than 10, then increase timeout to 10.

And, step 8 says this:

> Optionally, wait a further user-agent defined length of time.

And, it includes this note:

> This is intended to allow user agents to pad timeouts as needed to
>   optimise the power usage of the device. For example, some processors
>   have a low-power mode where the granularity of timers is reduced; on
>   such platforms, user agents can slow timers down to fit this schedule
>   instead of requiring the processor to use the more accurate mode with
>   its associated higher power usage.

Answer (score 1):

All timeout/interval/schedule functions are excepted to be run slower.

It is a nature of computer and very common in OS that there are many things CPU need to handle and too costly(and not possible) as a real-time system.

If you read theirs API https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval , it said "AFTER a specified delay" and "fixed time delay between each call". They are not saying not "on a specified time" nor "called on fixed period"