# node setInterval() way too slow

Tags: node.js, setinterval

Im doing this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    // some stuff that takes not even 1ms
    console.log(Date.now())
}, 50);
```

turns out it runs every ~70 ms or so. This is in node and nothing heavy is running on my machine at all.
I am aware of setInterval / setTimeout not always running perfectly, but running at ~70 ms when i put 50 is something ive never seen.

Comment: I think this has already been answered in a previous question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981382/setinterval-delays-not-accurate. See the answer for more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setInterval delays not accurate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23981382/setinterval-delays-not-accurate)

Answer (score 0):

Either the machine is slow, or node.js is running too many processes at once.

If not, you can use a `for` loop:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // Do what you want here.
  }
}, 500);
```

Please **note** that if you make it too fast, your machine will have problems.